# unique value in hash while merging their keys

Tags: perl, hash

I have a file with tab separated columns like this:

TR1"\t"P0C134

TR2"\t"P0C133

TR2"\t"P0C136

Now I split these into two arrays (one for each column values) then convert them into hashes but I want to remove the duplicates (here its TR2) while merging their right column values...something like this TR2=>P0C133,P0C136...how is it possible?? is there any function to do it in perl??

```
for($i=0;$i<=scalar@s_arr;$i++)
{
 if($s_arr[$i] eq $s_arr[$i+1])
  { push(@temp,$idx_arr[$i]); }

 else
  { 
   if(@temp eq "") 
    { $s_hash{$s_arr[$i]}=$idx_arr[$i]; }
   else
    {
      $idx_str=join(",",@temp);
      $s_hash{$s_arr[$i]}=$idx_str;
      @temp="";
     }
   }
}
```

this is code I've written where @s_arr is storing left column values and @idx_arr is storing right column value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid using two arrays and perform what you want in one fell swoop treating the left-side value as the hash key and making it an array reference, then pushing the right-side values that correlate with that key onto that aref:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;

while (<DATA>){
    my ($key, $val) = split;
    push @{ $hash{$key} }, $val;
}

print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
TR1 P0C134
TR2 P0C133
TR2 P0C136
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'TR1' => [
        'P0C134'
    ],
    'TR2' => [
        'P0C133',
        'P0C136'
    ]
};
```

Comment: :O The code in the answer I was preparing was identical! Except I was spliting implicty on `\t` instead of `\s+` (the right hand string may have spaces in it)

Comment: :) yep, it's a pretty common code idiom to get to where the OP needed to be

Comment: Can I suggest rather than `split /\s+/` that `split;` is all that's needed - they're almost the same, it's just the latter skips leading whitespace (which is moot). Both work, but I feel the latter is clearer. (

Comment: @Sobrique: agreed, and fixed. To be honest, I never realized (or had somehow forgotten) that `split` split on more than just a single whitespace char by default. Learned something new, I did!

Comment: @stevieb ....my man you must be godly being...you reduced my 18lines code to 3 lines...how I can I learn perl like this ??...and yes may you please explain "push @{ $hash{$key} }, $val;" and where did you choose the keys to be unique ????

Comment: @sangramjitbasu: You'll learn things like this the longer you write Perl :) Keys in a hash are always unique, so what happens is, if the left-hand value in the CSV is not yet in the hash when we first come across it, we create it as a key. If it is seen again, we add the next right-hand side value to the array held by the key.

Comment: @stevieb...okei...but now there's a small problem my command for printing the hash is     while (($k,$v)=each %hash){print "$k\t@$v"}    and in the output the multiple values for a certain key are seperated by new line but I want it tab or comma seperated, which some how I can't bring in !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want that same structure output use hash of hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @arr = <DATA>;
my %hash;

foreach (@arr)
{
    my ($k,$v) = split(/\s+/,$_);
    chomp $v;
    $hash{$k}{$v}++;
}

foreach my $key1 (keys %hash)
{
    print "$key1=>";
    foreach my $key2 (keys $hash{$key1})
    {
        print "$key2,";
    }
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
TR1 P0C134
TR2 P0C133
TR2 P0C136
```

Output is:

```
TR2=>P0C136,P0C133,
TR1=>P0C134,
```